# How to split string and take characters from it?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, file, split

Have next lines:

```
var line1 = File.ReadLines(@"input_5_5.txt").Take(1).ToArray();
string[] u = line1.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
int[,] result = new int[u[0], u[1]];
```

Need to split and take characters from line1 to initialize size of array but it runs error about word "Split".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`line1` is an array.

You need to cast it to string:

```
(line1[0] as String).Split(...
```

or simply

```
line1[0].Split(...
```